# Jfrog build retention deletes builds at random (instead of deleting the oldest build) using artifactory cloud

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I made no code changes- seems like this just started happening

I use the plugin in my jenkins pipelines like this:

```
def artifactory = Artifactory.server 'me.jfrog.io'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
def maxBuilds = 5

def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
          "pattern": "(*)",
          "target": "dev-builds/myapp/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/{1}"
        }
     ]
    }"""

buildInfo.name = "dev_myapp" // namespace build under "dev_<app-name>"
buildInfo.number = env.BUILD_NUMBER
buildInfo.env.capture = true
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: maxBuilds, deleteBuildArtifacts: true, async: false

artifactory.upload spec: uploadSpec, buildInfo: buildInfo
artifactory.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

When build retention runs it seems to just randomly pick an artifact under "dev-builds/myapp/" not the oldest one

Comment: Buikd retention deletes all the artifacts of the builds specified.
What do mean then by "randomly pick an artifact under "dev-builds/myapp/" not the oldest one".
Why would you expect it to delete the olderst artifact under "dev-builds/myapp/"?

Comment: How does maxBuilds decide which builds to delete then? I set it to five and there are six builds- how does it choose which of those to delete? seems to be random but I would expect it to delete the oldest because that seems like pretty obvious expected behavior

Comment: As far as I can see, if you set maxBuilds to X, all builds are deleted, except for the X newest ones.

Comment: What does that mean? I have 6 builds and retention is set to 5. Which one will it delete the oldest? sounds like X newest ones means oldest